# What is the difference between multiple data sources and multi tenancy?

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

In context of mongodb and gorm, If we need to have different databases for different clients, then are multi-tenancy (With Database mode) and multiple data source approach are 2 solutions to achieve the same thing or is there any difference between them?

Multiple Data Source Solution:
http://gorm.grails.org/latest/mongodb/manual/#multipleDataSources

Multiple Tenant Solution:
http://gorm.grails.org/latest/mongodb/manual/#multiTenancy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well they are not meant to achieve the same purpose

tldr;
Multiple Data Source is meant to have different databases (collections if you only plan to use mongodb) for different objects while Multi Tenant will store the same object but add a discriminator to identify client specific data.

If your question is about supporting *different databases for different clients* the answer will be to go with multi tenant

**Multiple Data Sources**

Grails supports (for long) to have multiple database for the same application (it can be different db vendor or different db from same vendor). The purpose is to have specific data stored in a different db/namespace.

For example, you can decide to have a db for all core entity of your business and to have a dedicated db for all audit/logging things. When using multiple data sources you will map an object to a dedicated datasource

**Multi Tenancy (with database tenant as per OP context)**

In mutli tenancy (database tenant) on the other hand, grails will have a single database schema for your client to store all the objects. so data from Client A will be in another db than Client B. Grails will have some default tenant resolver (that you can still override if needed) which will manage to determine which database needs to be queried depending the context.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Frederic, this is what I thought. Multi Tenancy seems to be answer for me and I will implement that. However, theoretically speaking, in a scenario where for example there are only 3 clients, and we need different mongodb databases(with same collections/documents), the same result can be achieved by both multiple data sources and multi tenancy with Mode=Database. right?

Comment: well lets say you store Purchase Order (PO) in your db, and then you want to list PO for a particular client, using multi tenancy you know you'll only get the current client POs, but if you implement multiple data sources you need to implement yourself the mongo connection so that it will query in your client db and will not fetch all POs from the system

Comment: Neither "...while Multi Tenant will store the same object but add a discriminator to identify client specific data." nor "In mutli tenancy (database tenant) on the other hand, grails will have a single database schema for your client to store all the objects." are necessarily true.  GORM supports tenant per database, tenant per schema or tenant via discriminator.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown you're fully right but OP specifically mentioned multi tenancy with DB tenant

Comment: The OP includes "If we need to have different databases for different clients...".  Neither of the statements I quoted are true for that scenario, and neither are true in general.  They speak to 1 way that GORM could be used to support multi tenancy.